"Error Invalid token" in Azure's Early access playground (Preview) with GPT o1. How can I easily figure out which token is invalid?
I encountered "Error Invalid token" in Azure's Early access playground (Preview) with GPT o1. How can I easily figure out which token is invalid? (easily = not using dichotomy on prompt)

The same prompt works fine on https://chat.openai.com/ but I don't have o1 there.
